# Content after landing page area

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I'm new at coding and im learning HTML and CSS. So i made this landing page but I cant create any content after that below the container. If i make services or about section, they are stick to the landing page area what ever i do.

There's loading screen where is only one picture and after that the landing page appears after second or so. So I tired to create more content after that where is about section, footer etc but like I said, they are stick to top of the page and this landing page area. I have no idea why is it and how to fix that.

HTML code:

```
 <body>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="box1">

            </div>
            <div id="box2">
                <div id="text">
                        CREATIVEX<br> <span class="auto-input"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="box3">
                    <div id="container">
                        <div id="logo">
                           <h1>Creative</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div id="menu">
                            <ul>
                                <li>HOME</li>
                                <li>ABOUT</li>
                                <li>ABOUT</li>
                                <li>ABOUT</li>
                                <li>ABOUT</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <nav>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                               
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                       <button class="btn btn1">Hover Me</button>

                      
</div>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I see that you've provided some of your HTML, but not all of it. Could you please provide all of your HTML and any CSS you are currently using?

Comment: Ohh yeah. Sorry about that.

Comment: It says its something like 500 characters too long when I try to post it.

Comment: Try creating a minimal reproducible example (the bare minimum of code required to reproduce your issue) on something like codepen and include the link. Without access to the full picture, there really isn't a way to help.